# Uviews are not getting connected to controller

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Ember has a Application which has ApplicationView, ApplicationController and 'application' named template and 'main' named outlet and all these connect automatically.
eg.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend();
```

and

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
```

so whenever my application template renders its default controller is an automatic instance of

```
App.ApplicationController
```

whose properties i can access in the template. But why does it not works with other views and controllers, i.e. if I have

```
App.SongView = Em.View.extend()
```

and 
    App.SongController = Em.Controller.extend()
these two do not connect. I can use any property of

```
App.SongController
```

in my song template.
I can use like :

```
{{view App.SongView}}
```

and in the template:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='song'>
    {{name}}
</script>
```

and if i have a name property in App.SongController then it wont get picked up because its not connected to the View.
although i can do it like this

```
{{view App.SongView controllerBinding='App.songController'}}
```

but this requires the instance of App.songController in my js file and also using this approach we are hard-coding the controller to the template.
What is the best way for this?

**Update**
I am also attaching a js fiddle for my problem here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/K6KPJ/

Comment: Which version of ember are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to render a template and its associated controller and view, you can use the `{{render}}` template. It works similarly to `this.render` in the router.

```
{{render "song" song}}
```

This example will render the `song` template with an instance of `App.SongController` and `App.SongView`. It will set the `song` controller's `model` to the value of `song` in the current context.

Here is a [working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eqihif/1/edit) that illustrates how this works.

Comment: This approach was working if i was using this {{render}} helper in the application template. But in my case I am rendering my views using the appendTo method of the views to render them on my page. Reason behind this is that I am trying to create widgets, and I can't have a single application for controlling all my widgets. I have a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anshulguleria/vQpe6/) to show my problem here.
In this fiddle if I write {{render 'parent'}} in the application template and remove the creation of parent then it works fine, else give error TypeError: container is null

Comment: After 4 days looking to nice way to replicate this functionality I stumbled upon this. This is awesome, thanks!